# Can I learn Unity with only python experience?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'll finish my university python course next week and I'll say that I pretty much passed the beginner level in python. I wanted to experiment creating games in python but with research it came to me that using Unity will be so much better. Since ill be fairly free in the summer, will I be able to learn Unity and/or C# using learn.unity with only python experience? Or am I supposed to first learn C# thoroughly like I did with python then hop on into Unity? I'm not expecting myself to make a 3d game or something, just simple games/projects first until I get comfortable with coding.

Comment: Yes, people with Python experience are able to learn Unity. The law against it was thankfully repealed in 2017. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity is the best for games, unreal engine is also really good. I find unity is a bit more user friendly and easier to code in but Im sure its in part preference.Unity learn premium is free right now, there is tons of youtube tutorials (Brackeys is my personal favorite), generally you don't have to be a coding wizard. Like anything put in the hours and you will gradually improve your craft. https://learn.unity.com/course/beginner-scripting

Comment: Thank you! Got this question flagged therefore closed because it was opinion based. I'm new on stack overflow didn't know they're just mining factual questions. Good thing I posted the same question in 3 more different sites hehe.